# How to modaly present a view to choose UIImagePicker sourceType?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller, modalviewcontroller

What I need to do is present this half modal view with buttons before presenting the UIImagePicker Controller, as in the picture below:

[image]

I believe all the apps in the world dealing with UIImagePicker Controller have this 'pre-view' but I'm struggling with this for 2 days now and haven't yet find a way to accomplish this.

I've already googled a lot in this, but still don't know if this is a subview added to the main view, a modal view controller or some property of the UIImagePicker itself, as long as almost all the apps that i've searched have the exact same way of presenting it.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the UIActionSheet component. 
Here is a sample :

```
UIActionSheet * sheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]     initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"ADVICES_ADD_PICTURE", nil)
                                                        delegate:self
                                               cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"CANCEL", nil)
                                          destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                               otherButtonTitles:NSLocalizedString(@"WITHOUT_PICTURE", nil),NSLocalizedString(@"TAKE_PICTURE", nil), NSLocalizedString(@"CHOOSE_PICTURE", nil), nil];

[sheet showInView:self.view];
```

Comment: Thank you man, you've made my day!
Maybe you can help me with some more on this:

- Check which button was selected (selector?);
- Change button order;

Comment: Nevermind about the first question, i believe i should do this with 
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{}

Comment: Yes, you can also use the button title, it may be easier to read afterward.